# What's the purpose of the [ip] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

> IP stands for "Internet Protocol". It is one of the fundamental protocols that powers the internet. IP is how data is able to be routed to the correct destination - your computer is assigned an IP address, and when you need to get data back, that data gets sent to your IP address.

I still don't have any idea what this tag's supposed meaning is, nor what questions should be tagged with it.

Now, there's the `ip` utility which replaces `ifconfig`, but then the tag makes no mention of it.

What is the usage of the [ip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) tag, if any?

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the description of the [networking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) tag, you can see that the network section is organized by protocols and IP is one of them. Questions should be tagged with [ip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) if they are specifically related to the protocol and concepts relative to it. Topics relative specifically to [ip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) and for which [networking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) would be too broad are for instance, the routing table, the structure of an IP datagram, etc.

What I can see is that this tag is sometimes overused. For example, questions about DHCP should be tagged only [dhcp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dhcp). There is no need to also put [ip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) even if the question is about IP addresses.

If we want to make a tag for the `ip` utility, it should be distinct from the existing [ip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) tag. Perhaps [ip-utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip-utility)?

Comment: I'm probably the one who's been using the tag [tag:ip] the most, and I confirm that this is what I mean by it.

Comment: Oh, and the `ip` utility from the iproute2 suite is covered by the [tag:iproute] tag.

Comment: Ok, so no need for _ip-utility_. I didn't know about _iproute_ but its description is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: The IP tag wiki currently explicitly says "and IP addresses". I'll remove that. Should [tag:ip] be v4 only, or should it include v6?

Comment: We have a separate [tag:ipv6], so I'm going to guess v4 only. Though never mind, we have [tag:ipv4] as well...

Comment: @Gilles we have an ipv4 and ipv6 tags, what's the difference and how they have to be used?

Comment: @Braiam [tag:ipv4] for questions that are specific to IPv4 and wouldn't apply to IPv6 without profound modifications. [tag:ipv6] dually. [tag:ip] for questions that would apply (possibly with minor modifications) to both versions. The obvious, in other words.